# Issue searching through a Trie

Tags: python, trie

I have written a code that implements Trie data structure where it takes in a list of strings and the string's count.

```
lst = [['james',9],['chloe',20],['chlara',30]]
```

The strings are the names, and the integer value followed by it is the count. Once the trie is constructed, it prompts a user to enter a prefix,

```
userinput = ch
```

With that, the code will return the string chlara since it has a higher count compared to chloe which also has the prefix ch. I've managed to construct the Trie but I'm having difficulties with the search function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [None] * 26
        self.end = False
        self.frequency = 0
        self.goindex = 0
        self.index = 0

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def ord_char(self,key):
        ord_rep = ord(key) - ord('a')
        return ord_rep

    def add_word(self,lst):
        word = lst[0]    #word
        freq = lst[1]    #frequency of string

        word_len = len(word)    

        current = self.root    #start from root node

        for i in range(word_len):
            position = self.ord_char(word[i])

            if current.children[position] is None:
                current.children[position] = Node()

            current = current.children[position]

            if current.frequency > freq:
                continue
            else:
                current.frequency = freq
            current.index = position

        current.end = True  #end of string


def main():
    trie = Trie()

    for i in list2:
        trie.add_word(i)
    user = input("Enter a prefix: ")
    print(trie.prefix_search(user))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm being returned the incomplete string 'chla' and I'm pretty sure it's due to my search function being inefficient and not working properly.

**updated**

Issue I'm facing now is, if my prefix is 'aberr' I'm being returned 'aberration' instead of 'aberr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never traversing your trie properly. You have two nested `for` loops, and so only traverse two more nodes (characters) from your prefix.

I'm going to assume you want to return **one** result, even if there are multiple strings with matching suffix and matching count.

Use a `while` loop, and keep following the highest `count` value until you get to a node with no more children with a value that's equal to the count of the current node. Do verify that you `end` is True for that node, as that would indicate a bug in your word-adding code:

```
def prefix_search(self, prefix):
    # traverse the prefix
    current = self.root
    for c in prefix:
        current = current.children[self.ord_char(c)]
        if current is None:
            return None  # None is a much better return value than -1

    while current is not None:
        for child in current.children:
            if child is None:
                continue
            if child.count == current.count:
                # found first child with same score, continue from here
                prefix += chr(child.index + 97)
                current = child
                break
        else:
            # no children with equal score, this is the longest match
            assert current.end, "Data structure inconsistent"
            return prefix
```

Demo:

```
>>> trie.prefix_search('ch')
'chlara'
>>> trie.prefix_search('j')
'james'
```

and some of those edge-cases:

```
>>> trie.add_word(('chlarissa', 9))  # longer word, lower count!
>>> trie.prefix_search('ch')
'chlara'
>>> trie.add_word(('janet', 6))  # same length and score as james, won't be found
>>> trie.prefix_search('j')
'james'
```

and if there was an error in the data structure; this deliberately sets a wrong count:

```
>>> trie.root.children[9].children[0].count = 7  # 'ja', 7, so higher, but not an end node
>>> trie.prefix_search('j')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 59, in prefix_search
AssertionError: Data structure inconsistent
```

Comment: @MartihnPieters yes returning one result is what I'm looking for. Looking at how the while loop flows, I'm greatly shocked at how simplified it is compared to what i have attempted. Silly me! The assertion in the end is absolutely brilliant! Thank you so much for your time. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: come to think of it, wouldn't it be better if instead of going through all the child nodes denoted by 'for child in current.children', we can know where the next child containing the highest frequency string in an instant? I've implemented a 'go index' attribute into the Node that stores the next index of the highest frequency node and tried implementing it in the add_word function. Would love some advices for it.

Comment: @clink: sure, that'd work too, just be careful with the edge cases, such as the existence of a longer word with the same prefix, but a lower score. It's not that expensive to loop through 26 items though.

Comment: pardon me for asking but, yes indeed I'm running into problems with the edge cases. May i ask for some help on the edited code above in the add_word function? It seemed like i'm not working on the go index correctly

Comment: in the edited code above, if i feed in the input 'aberr' with frequency 8765 and 'aberration' with frequency 900, the program fails at the edge case you were warning me off when i enter the prefix of 'aberr'. I'm in a total lost.